# How to add Google analytics to windows8 mobile application using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, google-analytics

I am working on windows mobile market application.i would like to know how to apply google analytics to that application while updating in the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [GoogleAnalyticsSDK](http://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsSDK/) from Nuget, check out [the documentation](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/documentation) (it's very thorough!), and then thank [Tim Greenfield](https://twitter.com/timgreenfield) for all his work.

Note: The docs are in C#, but it all works for VB.Net.

Comment: Hi Shawn,its help full to me Thank you very much for sharing information